# How to use dictionary variables inside django static tag

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views, django-staticfiles

I am trying to concatenate a Django variable to an `img src`. I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag) to do it but still when I inspect the browser, the value doesn't show up. By the way the value that I am calling is `dict` type which looks like this >>> `djangoDict` output: `{<foreignModel: ModelValue>: <Product: Item Desc...}`

I was able to show the `ModelValue` using the 2 curly braces `{{ djangoDict }}` but I can't do it when concatenating with an address.

So here my code:

```
{% for dd in djangoDict %}
            {% with 'products/anotherFolder/'|add:dd|add:'/suffix.jpg' as myImg %}
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-img="{% static myImg %}">{{ dd }}</a>
            {% endwith %}
{% endfor %
```

This is what I get when inspecting element:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" data-img="/assets/suffix.jpg">ModelValue</a>
```

What I want to show up:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" data-img="/assets/products/anotherFolder/ModelValue/suffix.jpg">ModelValue</a>
```

Thank you so much for anyone that would help :)

Comment: use `{% for k, v in dict.items() %}` to loop through dictionaries

Comment: @RockyLi it didnt show up. The `img src` is still the same. The output is `<a class="dropdown-item" data-img="/assets/products/suffix.jpg">Item desc...</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a similar problem to mine which solves my issues on concatenating image path. [It is the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19975763/2698680) to my question.

I used `STATIC_URL` which is configured on settings.py

My code now looks like this:

```
{% for dd in djangoDict %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-img="{{ STATIC_URL }}products/anotherFolder/{{ dd }}/suffix.jpg">{{ dd }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found myself facing a similar problem I don't know if its exactly the same; I wanted to link a file in my static folder to my HTML file i.e.  `src=""`, the directory should come from a dictionary source.
Apparently you could just link it there directly. Here's part of my code ;

```html
{% for dic in posts %}
{% if dic.no == 1 %}
<img alt="" class="u-expanded-width u-image u-image-default src="{% static dic.src %}"><!--/product_image--><!--product_title-->
<h4 class="u-product-control u-text u-text-body-alt-color u-text-2">
<a class="u-product-title-link" href="#"><!--product_title_content-->{{ dic.name }}<!--/product_title_content--></a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And i could not understand Jeanawhou's answer

Comment: You could Just process the path on views and add it to the dictionary to be used in your html code like i did‍♂️.